# UITableView willDisplayCell Acting Weird, Cells borders adjusted only after reuse

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, border

I am trying to have 10 pixels gap between cells and the edge of the screen.  I implemented willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath and also the heightForCell since am using two different prototype cells in my table view.

The problem am having is really weird.  The cells are only adjusted when i pull the list up, am guessing only when they are reused!  check the images please.![enter image description here][1]

This is the initial screen:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/epl2n8a5zohhdmz/Edited.screenShot.01.png?dl=0

This is the screen after the table view is scrolled:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c81dx9wmaq0mgr5/Edited.screenShot.02.png?dl=0

Here is my code:

```
    - (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell   forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0;
    cell.layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, cell.bounds.size.height - 10);
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:207/255.0 green:207/255.0 blue:207/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(20, cell.frame.origin.y, 280, cell.frame.size.height);
    cell.frame = cellFrame;
    cell.contentView.frame = cellFrame;
    [cell.contentView alignmentRectForFrame:cellFrame];
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    }

   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[self.namesList[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Relation"] length] == 0) {
        return 69.0;
    } else {
        return 89.0;
    }
}

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSMutableString *details = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    UILabel *nameLabel;
    UILabel *relationLabel;
    UILabel *ageLabel;
    UILabel *dayLabel;
    UILabel *dateLabel;
    Helper *dateConvert = [[Helper alloc] init];

    if ([[self.namesList[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Relation"] length] == 0) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell3" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        relationLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:2];
        relationLabel.text = [self.namesList[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Relation"];
    }
    nameLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
    ageLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:3];
    dayLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:4];
    dateLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:5];

    [details appendString:[self.namesList[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Age"]];
    [details appendString:@")"];
    ageLabel.text = details;

    dayLabel.text = [dateConvert getWeekDay:[self.namesList[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Date"]];
    dateLabel.text = [self.namesList[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Date"];

    return cell;
}
```

I have spent days trying to find the problem :( every help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not make your life easier and design the cell in Interface Builder to have the 10 px space already. You can add a UIView, make that 10 px from top, left, right and bottom, then put you UI elements inside of that. I would suggest subclassing your UITableViewCells and have code in those to display your data and set the borders.

Comment: Thanks for the help Justing, you are embarrassing me :) i really don't know how to do that :( I know this is a bad design/coding, but am trying to get the app going and released and then start improving it!

Comment: How to do what? Adding the UIView to your UITableViewCell? All you do is drag and drop in interface builder like you did your other ui elements. 

If you are asking about subclassing UITableViewCell, you do that the same way you subclass a UIViewController, but select UITableViewCell instead from the Subclass of drop down after New File. Take your time to learn, pick up Big Nerd Ranch's book, iOS Programming. It will provide you a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks again Justin! i will give the book a shot, but currently i just want to fix this bug and release the app since i have already released the android version :(

Comment: Where you able to fix this? If so can you accept my answer. If you need more help, let me know.

Comment: Thank you Justin for your help! unfortunately i have not fixed it yet! working on other aspects of the app right now, i would rather fix and understand the bug than to create a custom cell in Interface Builder :(

Comment: You said "am using two different prototype cells in my table view." So that implies you already have the custom cell set up. All you need to do is add the UIView and size it accordingly. You can use the same code above just add UIView *borderView = [cell viewWithTag:TAGNUMBER] You don't have to subclass the UITableViewCell, thats just a suggestion to move some code into that object.